# Copying java source file from different maven project and modifying its package declaration

Tags: maven, maven-3

Suppose we have two different maven projects; project A and project B

Project B uses A and needs to dynamically (using maven pluggins ?) copy a source file "A.java" from project A, modify its package declaration and compile it (project B should have the same class from project A but with other package declaration ..)

I am trying to copy the source file from A to B before modifying the package declaration and compile all.

Is this the good approach ?

So, project A expose its java file as a resource

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/</directory>
      <includes>
    <include>**/A.java</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

But how can I copy this file to B (B is a dependency in A) ? does "maven-resources-plugin" enable to copy resources from a dependency project, and if so, how do I specify the property "directory" in "resource"
I tried by specify the location of the file in the jar dependency but it did not work

Do you have other propositions ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do this in maven, but I've seen it done with ant in other projects. You could create an ant script to do this (this [blog post](http://gslsrc.net/l005_repackaging_java_project_using_ant.html) explains which ant tasks you need to run), and then you can run that ant script from maven, using the maven-antrun-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved it by the following steps:

1 - Use "maven-dependency-plugin" to extract (unpack) what I want (the source files from the jar) of included artifacts.

2 - Use "maven-antrun-plugin" to execute ant commands, to replace the strings, create the new package and move modified sources ..
see [here](http://gslsrc.net/l005_repackaging_java_project_using_ant.html)

3 - Use "build-helper-maven-plugin" to point the compiler to the new source package in order to include them in the compilation phase

PS: These three steps must happen in the phase "generate-sources" !

Answer (score 0):

maven-resources-plugin enable you to copy java source anywhere before compiling (you can initialize phases) but the problem lies in package declaration in the java file. you need to modify it also and that is not simple in maven

But why you need to do so ? why you need to use the same code in two different packages ???